# Cumulative measure with a conditional reset

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the need of creating a cumulative measure that resets when a certain condition happens.

The target is to create the 'Longest Stock Out Period' measure. That will be inserted in a matrix visual like this.

| Date | No. of Negative Days | Longest Stock Out Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08-03-2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 09-03-2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-03-2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 11-03-2022 | 0 | 0 |

The logic is that 'Longest stock out period' should  cumulative sum 'No. of negative days' until 'No. of negative days' is 0, then it should reset.

This is what I have currently tried, which just computes a 0. I believe there should also be some logic in the measure regarding no. of negative days should not be 0 or alike.

```
Longest Stock Out =
VAR _date =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [No of Days],
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), 'Calendar'[Date] <= _date )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Measure**:

```
Longest Stock Out Period :=
VAR ThisDate =
    MIN( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR DateOfLatestZero =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] <= ThisDate
                && 'Table'[No. of Negative Days] = 0
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( 'Table'[No. of Negative Days] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] <= ThisDate
                && 'Table'[Date] >= DateOfLatestZero
        )
    )
```

Adapt so as to use your Calendar dates as required.